# C++: call cosntructor of base class in a derived class without a constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I want to make a simple wrapper `B` around a complex class `A`. `A` has many different constructors. The class `B` does not have any constructors, so how can I automatically pass the constructor arguments to the base class `A`, without needing to implement them all in `B`?

Here is a simple example of what I want to do:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
   A(int a);
   A(const& A);
   // etc ...
};

class B : public A
{
   int b;
};

void main()
{
   B b(0);  // Since B does not have a constructor, I want it to dispatch to A::A(int)
}
```

note: A is a class from some package so I can not simply add my `int b` to `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B`, you can *inherit* `A`'s constructors:

```
class B : public A
{
    using A::A;
    int b;
};
```

Then `B b(0);` will work.

Comment: That is so simple I should have been able to find it myself. Thank you very much!